# Multi Search in a stdClass Object variable?

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I am designing a database system (php class) in JSON and I want to do a multicriteria search function in the variable Object  stdClass (no problem with a single criteria)and I am blocked :-(

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [Deliveredon] => 04-30-2018 9:18 pm [Projectid] => 11201 [Title] => xxx[Client] => xxxx => [Orderby] => xxx [Editor] => xxx [Version] => 0.1 [Type] => Creation [Createdon] => 04-24-2018 4:00 pm [DateReadytoprocess] => 04-24-2018 4:00 pm [DateProcessing] => 04-30-2018 2:51 pm [Tags] => [Datecourte] => 30-04-2018 [Semaine] => 18 [Mois] => 04 [Annee] => 2018 [Heure] => 9:18 pm ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [Deliveredon] => 04-30-2018 7:10 pm [Projectid] => 10309 [Title] => xxx [Client] => xxx [Group] => [Orderby] =>xxx [Editor] => xxx [Version] => 2 [Type] => Editing [Createdon] => 03-20-2018 3:42 pm [DateReadytoprocess] => 04-25-2018 2:19 pm [DateProcessing] => [Tags] => [Datecourte] => 30-04-2018 [Semaine] => 18 [Mois] => 04 [Annee] => 2018 [Heure] => 7:10 pm )
```

for the system I created a php class, here is the function for searching with a single criteria

```
public function RechercheEnregistrementCritere($champ,$critere){
$retour=array();
$datas = $this->ToutEnregistrement();
foreach ($datas as $key => $row) {
    if($row->$champ == $critere ){$retour[]=$row;}  
}return $retour;}
```

I would like to create a similar function but with an array variable argument

Can you help me ? thanks in advance

Comment: *I am designing a database system (php class) in JSON*. Sorry, but makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, but just do the same with an array of $champ + $critere then in your function just loop through your array, do the same as you already do and return an array of anwser?

Comment: it's to have a flat database (nosql), so it makes sense :-)
The system is a php class for processing data in JSON.
if that makes no sense then why Vmware has developed Redis, Microsoft has developed Azure Cosmos and Amazon SimpleDB?